# Giraph ShortestPathExample java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, giraph

I have already run the SimpleShortestPathsComputation  on single node pseudo-distribution and I am currently trying to run it on a 2 node cluster on Ubuntu 14.04.
But every time I got the following Error: (Complete Logs below)

```
ERROR org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread: masterThread: Master algorithm failed with IllegalStateException java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectAllAddresses: Too many failures (1000).
```

Which seems to be the result of the NettyClient not being able to connect with the other node on port 30001 resulting in `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: rofti/192.168.0.103:30001`.
I already tried to open the port on both nodes as described  [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/giraph-user/201310.mbox/%3CCAAcgib35tQyROodNQrE3Se_39JsT5MiQVP=4v==X10jtOUfSVA@mail.gmail.com%3E)
and made sure that all host-names are written in only lowercase letters.  But that didn't change anything. I really appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Here are some Files and Logs:

Output of iptables -L :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp spt:30001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpts:30000:30010
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:2181
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

File: /etc/hosts  on master(rofti-ex58-ud3r):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       rofti-ex58-ud3r
192.168.0.101   master
192.168.0.103   slave rofti
```

Zookeeper configuration File: conf/zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000  
dataDir=/home/hduser/mydata/zookeeper
clientPort=2181  
initLimit=5  
syncLimit=2  
server.1=192.168.0.101:2888:3888  
server.2=192.168.0.103:2888:3888
```

Syslog logs 1:

```
2015-09-04 17:43:46,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2015-09-04 17:43:46,661 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2015-09-04 17:43:46,784 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2015-09-04 17:43:46,787 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@3c1e6a1d
2015-09-04 17:43:46,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 'org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspInputSplit, index=-1, num=-1
2015-09-04 17:43:46,927 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: setup: Log level remains at info
2015-09-04 17:43:46,967 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: setup: Starting up BspServiceMaster (master thread)...
2015-09-04 17:43:46,982 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: BspService: Path to create to halt is /_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_haltComputation
2015-09-04 17:43:46,982 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: BspService: Connecting to ZooKeeper with job job_201509041740_0002, 0 on master:2181,slave:2181
2015-09-04 17:43:46,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
2015-09-04 17:43:46,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=rofti-ex58-ud3r
2015-09-04 17:43:46,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_79
2015-09-04 17:43:46,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/jars/classes:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/jars:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000000_0/work:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/..:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000000_0/work
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000000_0/work/tmp
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.16.0-38-generic
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000000_0/work
2015-09-04 17:43:46,988 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=master:2181,slave:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster@77084cb5
2015-09-04 17:43:47,003 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server slave/192.168.0.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-09-04 17:43:47,005 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to slave/192.168.0.103:2181, initiating session
2015-09-04 17:43:47,225 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server slave/192.168.0.103:2181, sessionid = 0x24f9906beb90000, negotiated timeout = 40000
2015-09-04 17:43:47,227 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: process: Asynchronous connection complete.
2015-09-04 17:43:47,232 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: map: No need to do anything when not a worker
2015-09-04 17:43:47,232 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: cleanup: Starting for MASTER_ONLY
2015-09-04 17:43:47,420 INFO org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster: becomeMaster: First child is '/_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_masterElectionDir/rofti-ex58-ud3r_00000000000' and my bid is '/_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_masterElectionDir/rofti-ex58-ud3r_00000000000'
2015-09-04 17:43:47,490 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyServer: NettyServer: Using execution group with 8 threads for requestFrameDecoder.
2015-09-04 17:43:47,539 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyServer: start: Started server communication server: rofti-ex58-ud3r/127.0.1.1:30000 with up to 16 threads on bind attempt 0 with sendBufferSize = 32768 receiveBufferSize = 524288
2015-09-04 17:43:47,543 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: NettyClient: Using execution handler with 8 threads after request-encoder.
2015-09-04 17:43:47,546 INFO org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster: becomeMaster: I am now the master!
2015-09-04 17:43:47,823 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: process: applicationAttemptChanged signaled
2015-09-04 17:43:48,013 WARN org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: process: Unknown and unprocessed event (path=/_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_applicationAttemptsDir/0/_superstepDir, type=NodeChildrenChanged, state=SyncConnected)
2015-09-04 17:43:54,587 INFO org.apache.giraph.io.formats.GiraphFileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
2015-09-04 17:43:54,597 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
2015-09-04 17:43:54,598 INFO org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster: generateVertexInputSplits: Got 1 input splits for 1 input threads
2015-09-04 17:43:54,598 INFO org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster: createVertexInputSplits: Starting to write input split data to zookeeper with 1 threads
2015-09-04 17:43:54,668 INFO org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster: createVertexInputSplits: Done writing input split data to zookeeper
2015-09-04 17:43:54,729 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: Using Netty without authentication.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,741 WARN org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Future failed to connect with rofti/192.168.0.103:30001 with 0 failures because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: rofti/192.168.0.103:30001
2015-09-04 17:43:54,742 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Successfully added 0 connections, (0 total connected) 1 failed, 1 failures total.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,742 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: Using Netty without authentication.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,745 WARN org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Future failed to connect with rofti/192.168.0.103:30001 with 1 failures because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: rofti/192.168.0.103:30001
[....]
2015-09-04 17:44:12,314 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Successfully added 0 connections, (0 total connected) 1 failed, 999 failures total.
2015-09-04 17:44:12,314 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: Using Netty without authentication.
2015-09-04 17:44:12,316 WARN org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Future failed to connect with rofti/192.168.0.103:30001 with 999 failures because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: rofti/192.168.0.103:30001
2015-09-04 17:44:12,317 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: connectAllAddresses: Successfully added 0 connections, (0 total connected) 1 failed, 1000 failures total.
2015-09-04 17:44:12,317 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: Using Netty without authentication.
2015-09-04 17:44:12,317 ERROR org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread: masterThread: Master algorithm failed with IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectAllAddresses: Too many failures (1000).
    at org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient.connectAllAddresses(NettyClient.java:488)
    at org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyMasterClient.openConnections(NettyMasterClient.java:76)
    at org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster.coordinateSuperstep(BspServiceMaster.java:1605)
    at org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread.run(MasterThread.java:124)
2015-09-04 17:44:12,318 FATAL org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: uncaughtException: OverrideExceptionHandler on thread org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread, msg = java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectAllAddresses: Too many failures (1000)., exiting...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectAllAddresses: Too many failures (1000).
    at org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread.run(MasterThread.java:194)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: connectAllAddresses: Too many failures (1000).
    at org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient.connectAllAddresses(NettyClient.java:488)
    at org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyMasterClient.openConnections(NettyMasterClient.java:76)
    at org.apache.giraph.master.BspServiceMaster.coordinateSuperstep(BspServiceMaster.java:1605)
    at org.apache.giraph.master.MasterThread.run(MasterThread.java:124)
```

Syslog logs 2:

```
2015-09-04 17:43:52,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2015-09-04 17:43:52,797 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2015-09-04 17:43:53,162 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2015-09-04 17:43:53,170 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@320ca662
2015-09-04 17:43:53,407 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 'org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspInputSplit, index=-1, num=-1
2015-09-04 17:43:53,544 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: setup: Log level remains at info
2015-09-04 17:43:53,782 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: setup: Starting up BspServiceWorker...
2015-09-04 17:43:53,828 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: BspService: Path to create to halt is /_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_haltComputation
2015-09-04 17:43:53,829 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: BspService: Connecting to ZooKeeper with job job_201509041740_0002, 1 on master:2181,slave:2181
2015-09-04 17:43:53,856 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
2015-09-04 17:43:53,856 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=rofti
2015-09-04 17:43:53,856 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_79
2015-09-04 17:43:53,856 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-09-04 17:43:53,856 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/jars/classes:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/jars:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000001_0/work:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/..:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000001_0/work
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000001_0/work/tmp
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.19.0-26-generic
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2015-09-04 17:43:53,857 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201509041740_0002/attempt_201509041740_0002_m_000001_0/work
2015-09-04 17:43:53,859 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=master:2181,slave:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.giraph.worker.BspServiceWorker@5fc3d61f
2015-09-04 17:43:53,899 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server slave/192.168.0.103:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-09-04 17:43:53,899 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to slave/192.168.0.103:2181, initiating session
2015-09-04 17:43:53,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server slave/192.168.0.103:2181, sessionid = 0x24f9906beb90001, negotiated timeout = 40000
2015-09-04 17:43:53,990 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: process: Asynchronous connection complete.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,107 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyServer: NettyServer: Using execution group with 8 threads for requestFrameDecoder.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,215 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyServer: start: Started server communication server: rofti/127.0.1.1:30001 with up to 16 threads on bind attempt 0 with sendBufferSize = 32768 receiveBufferSize = 524288
2015-09-04 17:43:54,223 INFO org.apache.giraph.comm.netty.NettyClient: NettyClient: Using execution handler with 8 threads after request-encoder.
2015-09-04 17:43:54,238 INFO org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager: setup: Registering health of this worker...
2015-09-04 17:43:54,304 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: getJobState: Job state already exists (/_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_masterJobState)
2015-09-04 17:43:54,323 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: getApplicationAttempt: Node /_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_applicationAttemptsDir already exists!
2015-09-04 17:43:54,339 INFO org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspService: getApplicationAttempt: Node /_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_applicationAttemptsDir already exists!
2015-09-04 17:43:54,359 INFO org.apache.giraph.worker.BspServiceWorker: registerHealth: Created my health node for attempt=0, superstep=-1 with /_hadoopBsp/job_201509041740_0002/_applicationAttemptsDir/0/_superstepDir/-1/_workerHealthyDir/rofti_1 and workerInfo= Worker(hostname=rofti, MRtaskID=1, port=30001)
```

Comment: have you enabled ssh password-less authentication between all of your nodes?

Comment: Yes the nodes can connect via ssh without password to each other and themselves